# PHP environment problems

Tags: php, web-services, call

when i develop my web, i get a crazy problem, i cant find the solution for this.

```
if ( $this->client == null ) {
    $this->client = Client::getInstance();
}
```

i run x-debug with my project, and get the crazy result
`$this->client == null` return `true`but
the code in block (`$this->client = Client::getInstance();`) is not called

```
if ( $this->client == null ) { //return true
        $this->client = Client::getInstance(); //not called
}
var_dump($this->client); // $this->client == null return false
```

if anyone can have a solution or causal for this crazy problem, please help me

Comment: Are you sure Client::getInstance() is returning you a valid object?
Try dumping var_dump(Client::getInstance())

Comment: @new_sys_admin i think this is not problem because the line $this->client = Client::getInstance(); not called

Comment: Can you try dumping Client::getInstance()  before the if block?

Comment: @new_sys_admin how are crazy:
var_dump($this->client);
if ( $this->client == null ) {
   $this->client = Client::getInstance();
}
var_dump($this->client);
not print anything but in the expression column i can see the follow:
at the line if...: $this->client is <Uninitialized>.
the code in block if is not called.
at the line var_dump affter: $this->client is Client object @@

Comment: Could you try the following code? http://codepad.org/8iO2sNJP

Comment: @new_sys_admin yes, the code var_dump(Client::getInstance()); run correctly,it print a Client object, but then nothing changed

Comment: Can you try if(is_null($this->client))  instead of if($this->client == null) ? I doubt the if condition succeeds. Also, try printing something in the if condition so that you are doubly sure

Comment: @new_sys_admin same result, i think the problem is my local PHP config because other member in my team run this code correctly, i dont known where is my problem Zzz